# Any JS library to do animation on scroll?

Tags: javascript, web-development, css, jquery, animation

I visited a website https://www.beargrylls.com/ and found a awesome animation on scroll. There are few famous libraries like scrollmagic and AOS for on scroll animation but I did not able to do similar animation like the above website. It seems like a layered animation for example zoom in and out of side images almost 2x but mountain image zooms in and out just a little bit and at the end then all change with a video...

Please suggest me so library or code example for something similar to it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this link set of scroll animation libs: https://www.cssscript.com/tag/scroll-animation/

Comment: Thanks! Got one from the link you shared :)